# Show archives by year from just one category

Tags: categories, archives

yesterday @jas helped to how to show archive by years in my nav. It works fine, but there is the second one little problem.

The @jas's solution filter me posts from all categories by year, I'd need to add filter to just one category.

The function which add me years to my navigation is:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'ravs_add_menu_parent_class' );

function ravs_add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
   //print_r($item);//print each menu item an get your parent menu item-id
   // get your menu item ID use that ID in below code and you can remove this code after getting ID 
  }
  GLOBAL $wpdb;
  $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );



  foreach($years as $year){
    $link = array (
          'title'            => $year->year,
         // 'title'            =>($year->year == date('Y') ) ?  'News (Category)' : $year->year, // this is how you want to print latest year as "News (Category)" 
          'menu_item_parent' => '13',  // my menu id is 13 ie: ID of menu name test under which years links are displayed 
          'ID'               => '',
          'db_id'            => '',
          'url'              => '/'.$year->year  // to create url of menu item 
      );
    $items[] = (object) $link;
  }
  return $items;    
}
```

Is there someone who helps me to extend it to category 'news' (if ID is needed, the cat's ID is '4').

Thanks for all.
Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question clearly that we just need to get post in that submenus from only cat id  = 4 , this will make your archive.php to work only for cat id = 4

Please add below code to **functions.php**:

```
function wpse75668_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {


   if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {

      if ( is_date() ) {

        $query->set( 'cat', '4' );
     }
   }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse75668_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are great, really. I see everything what I need is to modify `functions.php`, but I don't know the correct filters, vars, etc. It seems to work, my friend!

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so sorry .
Why don't you try using WP_QUERY .

You can learn about WP_Query either from codex or personally i like tutsplus mastering wp_query.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-an-introduction--cms-23023

You are using $wpdb to fetch data from database. But i think it is probably not the best way  although it works :)

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but I'm not a WP dev and this code showed me anybody in here and works (makes what I needed). Don't know how to _try using my WP QUERY_. Any idea?